# I don't understand this Java program

Tags: java

This an example of a programming book that I understood , however I am facing a big issue : the MonthlySales.txt has not been established and explained by the author of the book . At the end of the program here's what is asked : Enter the name of the file containing 30 days of sales amount : MonthlySales.txt

```
The total sales for the period is : 56.437.42
The average daily sales were : 1881.25
```

Here's the program :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SaleReport {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



        final int NUMDAYS = 30 ;
        String fileName ;
        double totalSales ;
        double averageSales ;

        fileName = getFileName();

        totalSales = getTotalSales(fileName);

        averageSales = totalSales / NUMDAYS ;

        displayResults(totalSales, averageSales);

        System.exit(0);


        }

    public static String getFileName()

    {
        String file ;

        file = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter the file name for 30 days sales ");
        return file ;

    }

    public static double getTotalSales(String fileName) throws IOException

    {
        double total = 0.0 ;
        double sales ;

        File file = new File(fileName);

        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        while( inputFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            sales = inputFile.nextDouble();

            sales += sales ;
            }

        inputFile.close();
        return total ;
    }

    public static void displayResults(double total , double avg)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,String.format(" The total sales for the period is $%,.2f\n"+

            "The daily average sales were $%,.2f ", total, avg  ));
    }

}
```

Comment: I never dealt with java , but i think this code simply counts the lines of the file you input

Comment: And i think theres a line missing. Total is always 0.0 isnt it?

Comment: I think you have to change sale += sales to total +=sales

Comment: You are correct : it should be total += sales ;

Comment: Thanks Jonas but however what do you think could be on the MonthlySales.txt ? to get these figures : The total sales for the period is : 56.437.42
The average daily sales were : 1881.25 . Do you believe that the program just read the 2 lines or it actually calculate something ?

Comment: I JUST FOUND OUT WHY IT DOES NOT WORK AND THAT'S RIDICULOUS!!

Comment: I use : import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 instead of : import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;   why???  of the imports is that IMPORTANT ? Because I had no errors in my class but it would not compile unless I get the imports packages in that orders : import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

Comment: If you use Eclipse, press Ctrl+Shift+O to get the right imports for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program reads lines from a file `MonthlySales.txt` and converts them to double. So if there are 30 sales in a file, each sale has to be in a new line. As long as there is a line to be read by `Scanner`, `while` loop keeps going, `Scanner` will pick up the next number it sees in a file and return it and it will add to the `sales` variable.

Make a txt file somewhere on your computer and put in it 30 numbers in 30 lines. When the program asks you for a path, enter it and your program should work. Also change `sales += sales` to `total += sales`.

Comment: I did create a file called MySales.txt and I entered 30 lines of numbers . However it gives me as errors :Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: MySales.txt (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
 at SaleReport.getTotalSales(SaleReport.java:49)
 at SaleReport.main(SaleReport.java:20)

Comment: It cannot find the file : MySales.txt and it is there!

Comment: @Freddy53 the file should be in the working directory of the app. Or specify an absolute pathname (e.g. `C:/MySales.txt` when prompted.

Comment: Matthiew the path was correct , the file was there but after 2 hours of debug I realized that my import java packages were not totally the same as the author of the book. I imported my packages as I was writing the code  and despite no error at all in the code it will pop up error listed above. So I copied the import packages first as suggested by the book : import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane  Then only it the code run smoothly. So I cannot write my code in Java and imported the packages on the fly as suggested by the Eclipse/Java ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are in files input/output section of the book

the author of the book want demonstrate a use case of files, imagine that you have a magazine or something like this and when you buy a product you put it's price in the file(manually or not we don't care here) and at the end of the month you want get total sales and the average of sales in one Month(30 days), so the text file should contain a prices of products that have been bought.

by changing `sales+=sales` to `total+=sales` you will get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dQ72.png) (if we suppose that we have just five sales).

which is the result that we should get:

> 1+2+3+4+5=15

and

> 15/30 = 0.5

Comment: The text file should be in the project folder, right click on the project folder in Eclipse select New->File, it will ask you for a name, name it as you want (sales.txt ..) and this works with me

Comment: The imported packages as suggested by Eclipse when I was writing my code were : import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  but despite no errors it will pop up errors at run time : Only when I changed the imported packages to : import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  It run properly Why is that ?

Comment: for me it works fine with : `import java.io.File;`  `import java.io.IOException;` `import java.util.Scanner;`  `import javax.swing.JOptionPane;` , this shouldn't be the problem may be you changed something else.